# Audit log of who/what creates new records

Tags: history-tracking, dml-operations

There are concurrent creations of multiple records happening in the org. We want to track the creation of record(standard/custom sObject). We also want to see which user is creating/updating that record and its timestamp.
We want to track dml operation. (We do not want to track triggers or apex class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to do this on a large scale and the only solution which I found is using '**Enable Login Forensic**s'.

The API which we used is **LightningUriEvent**:
It detects when a user creates, accesses, updates, or deletes a record in Lightning Experience only. This object is available in API version 46.0 and later.
I was able to retrieve data of sObject, timestamp, and user using below SOQL==>

*SELECT  EventDate, QueriedEntities, recordid, Operation, userid, UserName, UserType FROM LightningUriEvent*

For Classic salesforce, we have '**UriEvent**'.

**Resources:**
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=real_time_event_monitoring_overview.htm&type=5

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_lightningurievent.htm

Answer (score 1):

When a record is created, it has a number of fields that are "stamped" by the platform. Two of these fields are `CreatedByID` (who created the record) and `CreatedDate` (self-explanatory). You can pull this information via a report, a batch job, APIs, ...